# Extracting coefficients with a nonlinear Kernel using sklearn.svm python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, data-fitting

This may not be possible in theory, if so please elaborate.

I am trying to fit some data with Python's sklearn SVM class [sklearn SVM class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html)

When I use a linear kernel, I can extract the coefs using get_params method where

> coef_ : array, shape = [n_features] if n_classes == 2 else [n_classes,
>   n_features] Weights assigned to the features (coefficients in the
>   primal problem). This is only available in the case of linear kernel.

So I can find the equation of best fit that depends on all the independent variables, and am able to use this equation elsewhere.

Is it possible to do the same (get a non-linear equation) from a nonlinear kernel (like the RBF or the polynomial kernel) using sklearn?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc):

> The decision function is:
>
> [image: \operatorname{sgn}(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \alpha_i K(x_i, x) + \rho)]
>
> ...
>
> This parameters can be accessed through the members dual_coef_ which holds the product `y_i alpha_i`, `support_vectors_` which holds the support vectors, and `intercept_` which holds the independent term \rho ...

("support vectors" means the x_i in the decision function equation).

Each kernel has a [different function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#kernel-functions), which you'll need to understand to compute the K(x_i,x) term.